# Is Scrum framework or methodology?

Tags: scrum, agile

As per my understanding, Scrum is a Framework. Following is my view of the Scrum Framework and I would like to hear your ideas as well.

The methodology is a set of principles and practices which can be used to guide processes while the framework is real or conceptual structure intended to serve as a support or guide for the building of something. Agile is methodology since it provides a set of values and principles to guide software development. Any process which can be aligned with values and principles is Agile and there is no need of a framework for being in Agile. Scrum guide itself encourages to follow the defined structure to practice Scrum. Further, it says if you violate any of the Scrum practices defined by Scrum guide, you are not doing Scrum. The Scrum provides a conceptual structure to developing software as it is a framework. In general, a Methodology is an open boundary process while the framework is a closed boundary.

Finally, the most important thing is we must ensure Agile values and build an Agile mindset for being Agile rather than doing Agile. If you focus more on the Scrum framework, probably you will be stuck in the closed boundary. (This will leads to doing Agile). To being Agile you must focus more on Agile values and practices.

Answer (score 6):

The [Scrum Guide™](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html) states that **Scrum is a framework**:

> Scrum (n): A framework within which people can address complex
> adaptive problems, while productively and creatively delivering
> products of the highest possible value.
>
> Scrum is:
>
> - Lightweight
> - Simple to understand
> - Difficult to master
>
> Scrum is a process framework that has been used to manage work on
> complex products since the early 1990s. Scrum is not a process,
> technique, or definitive method. Rather, it is a framework within
> which you can employ various processes and techniques.

> Scrum is simple.  It is the opposite of a big collection of interwoven mandatory components. **Scrum is not a methodology**.
> https://www.scrum.org/resources/what-is-scrum

[Lunivore](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/790/lunivore) has mentioned the two descriptions in the answer for [What is the difference between framework vs methodology?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/3791/what-is-the-difference-between-framework-vs-methodology):

> A methodology is a set of principles, tools and practices which can be used to guide processes to achieve a particular goal.
>
> A framework is a loose but incomplete structure which leaves room for other practices and tools to be included but provides much of the process required.

I would disagree from this point that you have written in question: *Agile is methodology*. No, **Agile is a mindset**.

> Any process which can be aligned with values and principles is Agile and there is no need of a framework for being in Agile.

This is absolutely correct.

Comment: I agree with you. We should not call Agile as methodology. I will correct it. Agile is an umbrella of philosophy, methods and frameworks oblige with 4 values and 12 principles.